# Flutter: NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

my code when it found the data object it turns fine and i do not have any error. but when the data that i pass is not in the database it will return the exception. I don't know where to fix the error

[exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwjF7.png)

this is my code. the **widget.barcode** is i get from another file.

**modelRuangFasiliti.dart**

```
class RuangFasiliti {
  final String ruangfasiliti_id;
  final String ruang_id;
  final String fasiliti_id;
  final String kuantiti;
  final String namaruang;
  final String namafasiliti;

  RuangFasiliti({
    this.ruangfasiliti_id,
    this.ruang_id,
    this.fasiliti_id,
    this.kuantiti,
    this.namaruang,
    this.namafasiliti,
  });

  factory RuangFasiliti.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return RuangFasiliti(
      ruangfasiliti_id: json['ruangfasiliti_id'],
      ruang_id: json['ruang_id'],
      fasiliti_id: json['fasiliti_id'],
      kuantiti: json['kuantiti'],
      namaruang: json['namaruang'],
      namafasiliti: json['namafasiliti'],
    );
  }
}
```

**borangaduan.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:eaduanfsktm/api.dart';
import 'package:eaduanfsktm/sejarahaduan.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:eaduanfsktm/model/modelRuangFasiliti.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class BorangAduan extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idpengguna, barcode;
  BorangAduan(this.idpengguna, this.barcode);
  @override
  _BorangAduanState createState() => _BorangAduanState();
}

class _BorangAduanState extends State<BorangAduan> {
  final _key = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  TextEditingController controllerruang_id;
  TextEditingController controllerfasiliti_id;
  TextEditingController controller_namaruang;
  TextEditingController controller_namafasiliti;
  TextEditingController controllermaklumat = new TextEditingController();

  File _image;
  RuangFasiliti ruangfasiliti = new RuangFasiliti();



  Future<RuangFasiliti> getruangfasiliti() async {
    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.lihatruangfasiliti(widget.barcode));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(
        () {
          ruangfasiliti = RuangFasiliti.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
          controllerruang_id =
              new TextEditingController(text: "${ruangfasiliti.ruang_id}");
          controllerfasiliti_id =
              new TextEditingController(text: "${ruangfasiliti.fasiliti_id}");
          controller_namaruang =
              new TextEditingController(text: " ${ruangfasiliti.namaruang}");
          controller_namafasiliti =
              new TextEditingController(text: " ${ruangfasiliti.namafasiliti}");
        },
      );
    }

    return ruangfasiliti;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getruangfasiliti();
  }

  bool isloading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Borang Aduan"),
        ),
        body: isloading
            ? new CircularProgressIndicator()
            : new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  aduanbox(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget aduanbox() {
    return Container(
      child: Form(
        key: _key,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Card(
            //color: Colors.black,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: new TextFormField(
                            controller: controllerfasiliti_id,
                            readOnly: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "KOD FASILITI",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        flex: 2,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: new TextFormField(
                            controller: controller_namafasiliti,
                            readOnly: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "NAMA FASILITI",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        flex: 2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: new TextFormField(
                            controller: controllerruang_id,
                            readOnly: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "KOD LOKASI",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        flex: 2,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: new TextFormField(
                            controller: controller_namaruang,
                            readOnly: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "LOKASI",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        flex: 2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: controllermaklumat,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Masukkan Maklumat Kerosakan';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "MAKLUMAT",
                        hintText: "Masukkan maklumat kerosakan"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.image),
                        onPressed: getImageGallery,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                        onPressed: getImageCamera,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: _image == null
                        ? new Text("Tiada imej !")
                        : new Image.file(_image),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Container(
                    height: 45.0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                          tambahaduan(_image);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Material(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        elevation: 7.0,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'HANTAR',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getImageGallery() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;

    int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(100000);

    Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    Img.Image smallerImg = Img.copyResize(image, width: 500);

    var compressImg = new File("$path/image_$rand.jpg")
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodeJpg(smallerImg, quality: 85));

    setState(() {
      _image = compressImg;
    });
  }

  Future getImageCamera() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;

    int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(100000);

    Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    Img.Image smallerImg = Img.copyResize(image, width: 500);

    var compressImg = new File("$path/image_$rand.jpg")
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodeJpg(smallerImg, quality: 85));

    setState(() {
      _image = compressImg;
    });
  }

  Future tambahaduan(File _image) async {
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(_image.openRead()));
    var length = await _image.length();
    var uri = Uri.parse((BaseUrl.tambahaduan()));

    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile("aduanimages", stream, length,
        filename: basename(_image.path));
    request.fields['fasiliti_id'] = controllerfasiliti_id.text;
    request.fields['ruang_id'] = controllerruang_id.text;
    request.fields['maklumat'] = controllermaklumat.text;
    request.fields['idpengguna'] = widget.idpengguna;
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    var response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Image Uploaded");
      setState(
        () {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Aduan Berjaya",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 18.0,
          );
          Navigator.of(this.context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => SejarahAduan()));
        },
      );
    } else {
      print("Upload Failed");
    }
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
}
```

please help...

Comment: I am not sure but I guess the error occurs at getruangfasiliti() function. Can you try checking if response.body is null or empty before passing to the RuangFasiliti.fromJson

Comment: check my answer below. i show the picture  when it found the data VS there is no data in the database

Comment: what happens if you add a check in getruangfasiliti() (in borangaduan.dart file) as " if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.body != null) ".you may add an else condition to show the user that you didn't get any data.

Comment: it worksss but i changed to the  (response.statusCode == 200 && json.decode(response.body) != null). thank you so muchhhhhhh

Comment: Good, just mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check in getruangfasiliti() (in borangaduan.dart file) to verify if response.body is null or empty .you may have to add an else condition to show the user that you didn't get any data.